# Dealing with R8 + JvmStatic Annotation + Lambda in public API for Android Library written in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, obfuscation, android-library, android-r8

First of all, please note that I'm not expecting `why do you want to obfuscate library` comments. This is a genuine problem I'm asking about.

I have been having an issue dealing with R8/obfuscation with an Android library written in Kotlin.

I've a public API method which is annotated with `@JvmStatic` and that method takes a `Lambda` as parameter.

For example, take a look at code below,

```
typealias MyLambdaCallback = (String, Map<String, Any>) -> Unit

@Keep
object MyApi {

    private var callback: MyLambdaCallback? = null

    @JvmStatic
    fun setCallback(callback: MyLambdaCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
    }
}
```

I have added `@Jvmstatic` so that `Java` calling code can call the method statically rather than doing `MyApi.INSTANCE.setCallback()`

When I release the library without `minification`, everything is fine and calling code from both `Java` and `Kotlin` is written as expected.

But now I want to release the library while turning on `minification`.

That creates an issue.

Here is the error

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'void setCallback(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type static (declaration of 'com.demo.basic.Application' appears in /data/app/com.demo.basic-_0uJXPbtfs3UZ2Rp2h-RdQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)

Am I making a mistake somewhere or this is expected as some kind of limitation ?

**What did I Try ?**

1. Removing `@Jvmstatic` resolves the issue but it created ugly Java calling code
2. Kept `@Jvmstatic` but removed `Lambda` converting Lambda into an `interface with one method` and everything is working fine. Unfortunately `SAM for Kotlin classes` is not there yet, so calling `Kotlin` code looks ugly.

Comment: What version of the Kotlin compiler are you using?

Comment: @RyanM `1.3.72`

Comment: @RyanM I found that the problem is around `@Jvmstatic`. I update content of the Q. Take a look if you can help with something.

Comment: This is a great question with lots of details.  This really looks like a bug in the tools somewhere (i.e., not a mistake on your part) to me - I don't have time to dig into it at the moment, but I'll take a look at some point if I can find some time.

Comment: Okay. No problem. Thanks @RyanM

Comment: This is reported at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158393309.

Comment: @MortenKJ I only reported that today :)

Comment: @shaktiman_droid you'd better edit question and delete that "update" part as it is misleading: the answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R8 team has [fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158393309) this issue along with related issue [b/158400283](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158393309) in R8 version `2.1.42`

Fix should already be available in `Android Studio 4.1 beta` or higher, but if you're using stable `Android Studio 4.0` then add following to your top-level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:2.1.42'          // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z' // Your current AGP version.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is tracked on the R8 issue tracker http://issuetracker.google.com/158393309 which has more details.

The short story is that this has been fixed in R8 version 2.1.35, which can be used by making the following changes to the top level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:2.1.35'          // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z' // Your current AGP version.
 }
```